# How do I write a query to reverse search values from a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My knowledge in SQL is very limited and any help at all is much appreciated.
So I have this table with multiple columns out of which I need values from only column a and column b. Now both column a and column b has multiple duplicate values. It looks like:

```
Column A  Column B
Q              i
Q              ii
W              ii
E              iii
Q              iv
Q              i
E              i
```

So what I need is (I'll take the above table as example):
For Q (in column a) the values in column b are 1,2 and 4. I need the count of distinct values that coincide with i,ii and iv, i.e, Q,W and E. So i need it like:

```
Column A     Column C
Q               3
W               2 (i.e values coinciding with ii)
E               2 (i.e values coinciding with i and iii)
```

How do i do this?

Generally what I do is run the query for just Q or W or E.. get the distinct values for column B and then run the query again with the distinct values of column b for the count of distinct values in column A.. but right now i need to work with the entire table and not just one single value so its not possible for me to do this.
and I m working on snowflakes if that's relevant.
Thanks again!

Comment: what db system are you using? postgres, mysql, etc?

Comment: i m using snowflake

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use GROUP BY and COUNT DISTINCT

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) as ColumnC
FROM YourTable
WHERE ColumnA IN ('Q', 'W', 'E')
GROUP BY ColumnA
```

1. filter the rows to include only those with values in column A that are `'Q'`, `'W'`, or `'E'`
2. group the remaining rows by column A and count the distinct values in column B for each group

The result will be a table with two columns(first column shows the values in column A -- second column shows the count of distinct values in column B for each group)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, COUNT(DISTINCT B)
FROM SOME_TABLE
GROUP BY A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl
CREATE TABLE #tbl (ColA CHAR,ColB VARCHAR(3));  
GO  
INSERT INTO #tbl
VALUES
('Q','i'),
('Q','ii'),
('W', 'ii'),
('E','iii'),
('Q','iv'),
('Q','i'),
('E','i')


;WITH
A
AS
(
    SELECT
    t1.ColA
    ,t2.ColA  as ColA2
    FROM #tbl t1
    JOIN #tbl t2 on t1.ColB = t2.ColB
    GROUP BY t1.ColA,t2.ColA
)
SELECT A.ColA, COUNT(DISTINCT a.ColA2) 
FROM A
GROUP BY A.ColA
```

Comment: The CTE is simply joining each row to every one row where Column B is the same and removing any duplicates.  Once that is done, for each unique value of Column A, we can COUNT DISTINT each Column A value that has joined on the matching Column B